# Getting a Node using its hash table

Tags: c, algorithm, hashtable

If I have the following linked structured and each node has a hash table of its name as key and its value as its object. If I have a pointer to Node1, how would I go to Node 2, using the hashtable of Node 1 ?

Each node has a hash table of its name, and the node itself. but If I have a pointer to Node 1, how would I go to Node2 without using linked list structure, just using the hashtable.

```
struct Node
{
  hashtable[node_name, Node];

};
```

If I have `Node *node1;`
How would I go to node_2; using its hashtable ?

[image]

Comment: A hash-table is a *table*, it's supposed to contain multiple entries. Do you mean that the nodes contain the hash of the key, or an actual hash-table? What's the actual contents of the *table*? Please clarify, preferably by showing some code, including the definition of the node structures and other related structures (code says more than a thousand pictures).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have edited the question. Each node has a hash table, but that hashtable has the name of the node, and the value is the Node it self.

Comment: If you post code, please try to post *valid* code, or specify that it's pseudo-code.

Comment: Also, do the hash-table actually contain the *children* of the current node? It makes no sense to have a table containing only a single element, and have that single element pointing back to itself.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg its a pesudo code, but I hope it shows what I need

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If that hash table contains the childern of the current node, how would I go to Node 2 from Node 1

Comment: *"If that hash table contains the childern of the current node, how would I go to Node 2 from Node 1"* - then you **can't** go from Node 2 back to Node 1 using the hash tables.  Something has to be changed.  Options include storing the parent and/or other nodes in more hash tables (i.e. redundantly, with some cost to memory usage, and more complicated and likely slow updates as you insert/erase nodes), and/or have a `Node* parent_; ` in each `Node` so you can always go upwards and start searching other `Node`'s hash tables, or change your algo so you don't need to go from N2 to N1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have "node1", and want to find a child-node, then you need to find it in the has-table. Do do that, simply calculate the hash of the node you want to find, and check if it's in the table.

If the hash is in the table, you then have the wanted child-node, else there is no such child.

Comment: but If I want to find a child of the child of the child ?

Comment: so the parent will have all the childern in its hash table ?

Comment: @AndreAhmed Just continue down the tree, checking the has-table in each child-node.

Comment: but going down the tree, is a linked list search then, and I don't want that

Comment: @AndreAhmed It's only a linked list if the tree is arranged that way. You find the child-node in the root, then you find the grand-child in the child, and the grand-grand-child in the grand-child, etc., goind wherever the hash-table in each node tells you to go. That is how you search in a tree, what did you expect?